# detailTextLabel not showing, even with UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get a subtitle to show up in my table view's cells, but for some reason it isn't appearing. I am setting the cell's style to UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle, so that's not the problem. Here's the relevant code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NMADRestaurant *restaurant = [self.restaurants objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [restaurant name];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    CLLocation *restaurantLocation = [restaurant location];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:restaurantLocation];
    NSString *distanceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f km",(distance/1000)];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = distanceString;

    return cell;
}
```

If I NSLog distanceString, it displays properly. But when I NSLog(@"Label %@",cell.detailTextLabel.text), "Label (null)" is all that appears in the logs.

Comment: are you scure that  distance is no null?

Comment: Positive. When I do NSLog(distanceString), it prints out the distances perfectly.

Comment: try to print NSLog(@"%.1f", distance)

Comment: That prints the distances as expected.

Comment: I try to make a project with your code and works

Comment: If the cell is defined in a storyboard, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: will always return a non-nil cell, so your if (cell == nil) clause will never execute. You need to set the type to Subtitle in IB.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work on mine at first either, I had to go to my storyboard and then select my prototype cell. After that I went to Attributes Inspector and then changed 'Style' from Custom to one of the detail options and then it showed up fine.

And does this line:

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:restaurantLocation];
```

declare distance as a float? I wasn't sure what type of values you got so I had to make a

float distance = 0.5;

to be able to test it out, but maybe it was null bc you were calling it a float and it wasn't?

Good Luck

Comment: Simply look at the docs for `CLLocationDistance`. It is a synonym (`typedef`) for `double`. Using the `%f` format specifier is just fine for `CLLocationDistance`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi，notice:my English is bad.

Did you have this in your init or viewDidLoad method?

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"abc"];
```

Just comment it and try again. (i think the when the cell is first created, they don't apply the style subtitile because of this code, it use the default cell style.)

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment given the age of the question and you are looking for clarification. As a comment if the OP accepts it then you can turn it into an answer.